# How do I create an object of a type for which I only have the string name?

Tags: c#, .net

All I have from some configuration settings are the names of my classes as strings.
All my classes follow one interface.  But some follow a secondary different interface

So for example my 'tree' classes will all follow IRoots interface, but some may have different settings from each other.

```
coniferousTree : IRoots, IGreenLeafSettings
deciduousTree : IRoots, IGreenLeafSettings
specialtree1 : IRoots, INeonLeafSettings
specialTree2 : IRoots, INeonLeafSettings
```

So when I encounter the name of the tree in my XML file, I want to instantiate the exact object type for that tree AND apply the settings to the tree (as they are defined in the configuration file)

What I got stuck on was this
Say I'm at this Node in the XML

```
<Tree Tree="coniferousTree" Gsetting1="" Gsetting2="" Gsetting3="" />
```

(where those three settings would be the properties of the settings interface that are implemented in the tree object)

```
//first I read the attribute value from XML that indicated the tree object
string treeName = tree.Attribute("Tree").Value;  

//then try and instantiate the object
 Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath + @"\Tree.dll");
 var type = a.GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == treeName);
 var myObject = (IRoots)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But what I really want to get back is the actual object type not the interface type.  (because I want to apply the settings to it)

If I was on that particular node I want this

```
var myObject = (**coniferousTree**)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But I can't because I don't know ahead of time while coding that that is the type I need to cast it as.

Is there a nice way to solve this, without resorting to a bunch of if else statements to check for different settings interfaces.

Comment: Is it possible for all the tree types to inherit from an abstract base class that has a `public abstract void LoadSettings(XmlElement element);` on it? (Replace `XmlElement` with whatever type `tree` is in your code example)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Actually that's a good idea, thanks.  Does it have to be abstract base class,  or can I just add this method to the IRoot interface and have all my classes implement it their own way?

Comment: A method in `IRoot` would work, I only suggested a seperate class/interface because I thought `IRoot` was for tree roots. And I only suggested an abstract base class over a interface to force all of the different types of trees to implement it, but it easily could just be part of one of your existing interfaces.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  I ended up doing it this way, it greatly simplifies my code. But then I thought about what happens when you have a GUI?  (I'm thinking you won't read from the XML file to get settings but from the user interface instead). Will sticking with this implementation pose any restriction or problem when I implement the GUI?

Comment: You should post yor own answer showing how you implemented it. For the user interface I doubt you will run in to any problems, you will likely just set each individual property directly.

Answer (score 1):

If all that you need to do is move the settings from the XML file into the instantiated object, then I think what you are looking for is [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// Substitute code here to retrieve the property name/value pairs from the XML file 
var myProperty = "GSetting1";
var myValue = "ABC";

// See if the requested property actually exists in the class
var oProperty = type.GetProperty(myProperty, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
if (oProperty != null)
{
    // If it does, set its value based on what was retrieved from the XML file
    oProperty.SetValue(myObject, myValue, null);
}
```

Couple of notes on this:

1. You may need to coerce the data types that are read from the XML file into the type corresponding to the property, but the `PropertyType` property on the `PropertyInfo` object (returned by `GetProperty`), contains the information to help with this.
2. You can also use the `GetMethod` method on the `type` to find and execute methods (i.e. you could have a method to set values from the XML file).